# Jacobi's substitution for modular equations

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-integrals, modular-function

I have read that in his "Fundamenta Nova Theoriae Functionum Ellipticarum", Jacobi managed to solve the equation
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}} = \frac{pdy}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-l^2y^2)}}
\end{align}
for any odd prime $p$, by making a substitution $y=U(x)/V(x)$, where $U(x)$ and $V(x)$ are polynomials, and as a result he was able to get an algebraic relation between $k$ and $l$ (a modular equation).

Did Jacobi know this substitution would work or did he just guess it and found that it worked by laborious trial and error? Using what we know today, could we come up with this substitution and derive the relation between $k$ and $l$ more easily?

Comment: Some work in this field was already done by Legendre and Jacobi may have been influenced by him. The hallmark of Jacobi is that he put the entire theory of elliptic and theta functions on the foundation of transformation of elliptic integrals. Quite a marvelous achievement which makes the subject accessible to anyone having familiarity with calculus. The modern approach to these theories is way more difficult.